# php session check in jqm pages

Tags: php, jquery, session, jquery-mobile

i have been battling with a problem and i need to ask.
i implemented login, then redirect and session check on every page after login in a normrl php page like so,

```
session_start()
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin']==false){
header("Location: ../login.php");
}
```

but in JQM , it doesn't do the session check even if the code is on top of every php JQM page i have. i read in the docs that JQM pulls pages into DOM, istead of loading them.

how do you achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, when JQM sees a link, like

```
<a href="foo.php">Foo</a>
```

It automatically handles the click/touch event and uses XHR (Ajax) to request foo.php and inject it into the DOM. In your case, it requests foo.php, and your server side code notices the lack of a login, and send a response back saying it should load login.php instead. This should be picked up just fine by the AJAX request and handled.

I just did a quick test with ColdFusion and it worked fine. I had a link to test.cfm, but in there I had logic to say, if not logged in, redirect to test2.cfm. For me, it worked just fine.

Now - I assume cflocation is pretty similar to PHP's header(), but it may not be.

Comment: Also didn't use exit(); after the header redirect... that has got me several times.